# Login entra diretamente pelo google

Tags: javascript, api, login, google

Bom dia!
Utilizei a API de login do google em uma página do site. Ela pega as informações e funciona corretamente, entretanto, mesmo sem clicar no botão, ela já roda o js do google diretamente, sem possibilitar de certo modo que eu faça o "singOut" do sistema pois sempre que vou para a página de login, ele já pega automaticamente as informações e vai para a página dde redirecionamento.
Segue o código da página de login

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark" style="width: 350px"></div>

                <script>
                    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
                        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
                        var userID = profile.getId();
                        var userName = profile.getName();
                        var userPicture = profile.getImageUrl();
                        var userEmail = profile.getEmail();
                        var userToken = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;

                        //document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = userEmail;
                        if(userEmail !== ''){
                            var dados = {
                                userID:userID,
                                userName:userName,
                                userPicture:userPicture,
                                userEmail:userEmail
                            };
                            $.post('validarLoginGoogle.php', dados, function(retorna){
                                    if(retorna=="1"){
                                            window.location.href = "http://calangoeventos.eu5.net/telas/telaInicial.php";
                                    }
                                    }else{
                                            window.location.href = "http://calangoeventos.eu5.net/telas/complementoCadastro.php";
                                    }
                            });
                        }
                    }
</script>
```

O intuito do código acima é redirecionar o usário para a página inicial caso ele já tenha acessado antes e caso não, redirecionar para a tela de complemento do cadastro
E o código do meu validarLoginGoogle.php

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once("../funcoes/integracaoBanco.php");
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'userEmail', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'userName', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM Usuario WHERE email='$email'";
$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conexao, $result_usuario);

//Econtrado usuario com esse e-mail
if(($resultado_usuario) AND ($resultado_usuario->num_rows != 0)){
        $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);
        $_SESSION['usuarioLogado'] = $user;
        $result = 1;
    echo(json_encode($result));
}else{//Nenhum usuário encontrado
    $result = 2;
    echo(json_encode($result));
}
```

Comment: e se incluir um botão ou link para ele fazer o sign out?

Comment: Meu sign out só destroi a sessão do usuário depois de logado, pesquisei sign out na api mas não encontrei nada relacionado.

Comment: mas na verdade o problema não é exatamente o sign out mas sim controlar para que ele só logue no sistema quando clique no botão do sign in do google e não automaticamente pegando as informações que tinham sido geradas anteriormente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui você está fazendo uma validação que se os dados do Google forem validos e retornar 1 vai para a

```
telaInicial.php( window.location.href = "http://calangoeventos.eu5.net/telas/telaInicial.php")
```

Faz a validação retornando para o lugar que você precisa, é bem simples

```
$.post('validarLoginGoogle.php', dados, function(retorna){
 if(retorna=="1"){
     window.location.href = "http://calangoeventos.eu5.net/telas/telaInicial.php";
 }else{
    window.location.href = "http://calangoeventos.eu5.net/telas/complementoCadastro.php";
   }
});
```

Vi aqui também um erro, que pode atraplhar na sua validação

```
$.post('validarLoginGoogle.php', dados, function(retorna){
                                    if(retorna=="1"){
                                            window.location.href = "http://calangoeventos.eu5.net/telas/telaInicial.php";
                                    }
                                    }else{
                                            window.location.href = "http://calangoeventos.eu5.net/telas/complementoCadastro.php";
                                    }
                            });
```

Na linha 4 tem um fechamento que no caso fecha o `if` de validação, não possibilitando passar a validação pro `else`

Comment: Não compreendi muito bem, a validação com redirecionamento já estou fazendo, no caso da segunda observação, foi apenas erro de digitação pois suprimi um else if do código.

Comment: "pois sempre que vou para a página de login, ele já pega automaticamente as informações e vai para a página de redirecionamento", isso está acontecendo por que você passou em seu código que se a validação do Google for valida redireciona para a pagina inicial, não sei se você sabe, mas as `api` do Google tem `cookie`, portanto quando você entra a validação é feita automaticamente.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigada!

Comment: Mas não teria como controlar a utilização dos cookies? pois a unica forma de parar de acessar automaticamente é com o sign out e gostaria que só logasse quando o usuário clicar no botão.

Comment: `if(retorna=="1"){
          $("#botaodelogin").click(function(){
              window.location.href = "http://calangoeventos.eu5.net/telas/telaInicial.php";
          })
  }` 
Desta forma vai fazer a validação, se for correta ela vai esperar o clique no botão que você quiser para realizar o login

Comment: Funcionou :D brigadão!!

Comment: Não foi nada, se precisar estou aqui